# Pandas giving length must be equal error when trying to replace one column with another

Tags: pandas

I am trying to fill one column with another column if null. I tried 2 ways

```
df.NAME1 = np.where(df.NAME1.isnull(), df.NAME2, df.NAME1)
df['NAME1'] = df['NAME1'].fillna(df['NAME2'])
```

I get:
Lengths must be equal.

Comment: Can you show us the dtypes ?

Comment: Or at least `df.head()`, this is not enough to debug.